# Changelog for a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, entity-relationship

I want to design a changelog for a few tables. Lets call it table `restaurant`. Every time a user modifies the list of restaurants the change should be logged.

**Idea 1**

My first idea was to create 2 tables. One which contains all the restaurants `RESTAURANT_VALUE` `(restaurantId*, restaurantValueId*, address, phone, ..., username, insertDate)`. Every time a change is made it creates a new entry. Then a table `RESTAURANT (restaurantId*, restaurantValueId)` which will link to the **current valid** `restaurantValueId`. So one table that holds the current and the previous version.

**Idea 2**

It starts with 2 tables as well. One of them contains all current restaurants. e.g. `RESTAURANT_CURRENT`. And a second table which contains all changes `RESTAURANT_HISTORY`. Therefore both need to have the exactly same columns. Every time a change occurs the values of the 'current' table are copied into the history table, and the new version in the 'current'.

*My opinion*

Idea 1 doesn't care if columns will ever be added or not, therefore maintenance and adding of columns would be easy. However, I think as the database grows... wouldn't it slow down? Idea 2 has the advantage that the table with the values will never have any 'old' stuff and not get crowded.

*Theoretically I think Idea 1 should be the one done*

What do you think. Would you go for Idea 1 or another one? Are there any other important practical thoughts I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

The approach strongly depends on your needs. Why would you want a history table?

If it's just for auditing purposes, then make a separate `restaurant_history` table (idea 2) to keep the history aside. If you want to present the history in the application, then go for signle `restaurants` table with one of below options:

- `seq_no` - record version number incrementing with each update. If you need current data, you must search for highest `seq_no` for given `restaurant_id(s)`, so optionally use also `current` marker, allowing straighforward `current = true`
- `valid_from`, `valid_to` - where `valid_to` is NULL for current record

Sometimes there is need to query efficiently which attributes exactly changed. to do this easily you can consider a history table on attribute level: `(restaurant_id, attribute, old_value, new_value, change_date, user)`.

Comment: Oh ok - thanks! We would have a histrory table for audit purposes. So whenever we feel like there's something wrong. The user could open our application which would show all restaurants. If an entry seems wrong or the user wants to find out who created that entry and what has changed, he'd be able to pull up a history view which will show all recent modifications on that restaurant. Additionally there might be a second 'log-view' which will show all changes made on all restaurants in a grid-view (log)